# How to connect to an Oracle database through VS Code using an SID instead of Service Name?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-code, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to see if I can use VS Code to connect to the Oracle databases we use at my job. I installed the Oracle Developer tools extension for VS Code, but when I click to add a connection it is required that I use a service name.

VS Code Oracle Connection Form

[image: 1]

Does anyone know of a way I can use SID instead of a Service Name? All of our connections use SID.

I've tried the different options for connection type, however they all ask for fields that are not required of me to connect to the db. I've also used the SID as the Service Name, but was still unsuccessful in connecting.

Comment: All databases should have a service name available at the listener. The DBA should be able to tell you what it is. Technically speaking, SID for network connections was deprecated 20+ years ago.

Answer (score 1):

*All of our connections use SID.*

is something you should be looking at addressing as a side project. Services over SID became recommended in Oracle 8i (yeah you read that right...20 years ago)

But every database has an implicit service name equivalent to the SID so just entering the SID value should still get you connected without issue.

Of course, now that we're in the world of pluggable databases, this will pretty much force your organisation to move to services, because the SID is typically going to point to the root container whereas you will want to connect to the pluggable(s) that sit underneath it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, using a SID is not advised. You should be using a service name. But if you really want to use a sid, in the connection dialog choose "Easy Connect String/Connect Descriptor" connection type.

For connection string, use this descriptor, replacing your SID for "mysid", and your host or IP for "myhost":

(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS =
(COMMUNITY = TCP)
(PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = myhost)
(PORT = 1521)
)
)
(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = mysid))
)